# How can one properly set the table on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, borer-separating

If one has a pile of mixed flatware, how can one set the table on Shabbat without violating the *melacha* of *borer*? By selecting knives, spoons and forks from the pile, one is "selecting".

Comment: Are you sure that's a prohibited kind of selecting? Sounds like you're taking the item you want with your hand for immediate use in setting the table

Comment: Why can't you just take something at random repeatedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synopsis of ideas from [Jewish Pathways](http://www.jewishpathways.com/files/Borer_-_Part_4_Beyond_the_Edible.pdf):

If your flatware is already separated by type in a storage drawer / box (many people do this), then, there is no issue of *borer*.

There is no issue of *borer* if the table is set immediately prior to eating the meal.

Citing Shu"t *Igrot Moshe* Orach Chaim 4:74:11, if one wants to set the table ahead of time, he may lightly drop the mixed flatware on the table thus scattering the mix. By doing so, he has separated the pile, and then he may select what he needs.

A Teshuva from Rav Zalman Aurbach says that if one gains aesthetic pleasure by seeing a set table, this would be permissible use to set the table ahead of time, as well.